# Sort the elements of the array

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an array like the following:

```
$a= $array('PHP','HTML','JS','LARAVEL');
```

I want to sort the elements in the array, descending by the total number of characters of an element

```
$b= $array('LARAVEL','HTML','PHP','JS');
```

Please help me to descend the elements of the array, based on the number of characters in an array.

Comment: have a look at `usort` function

Answer (score 1):

I see you have the Laravel tag, so you can use Laravel collections with the [`sortByDesc`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortbydesc) function for that.

```
$array = collect(['PHP','HTML','JS','LARAVEL'])->sortByDesc(function($value) {
    return strlen($value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks i made the way over and was successful

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer solved your question, consider marking it as the solution so other users might find this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function sort($a,$b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}
$array = ['PHP','HTML','JS','LARAVEL'];
usort($array,'sort');
```